# Subscriber not returning value

Tags: java, kotlin, java-11

How to create a Flow.Subscriber in Kotlin?

```
    val body = this.bodyPublisher().map { p -> {
        val bs  = HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.ofString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        val fs = StringSubscriber(bs)
        p.subscribe(fs)
        bs.body.toCompletableFuture().join()
    } }.get()
```

It returns an empty string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.bodyPublisher().map { p -> {
    val bs  = HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.ofString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    val fs = StringSubscriber(bs)
    p.subscribe(fs)
    bs.body.toCompletableFuture().join()
} }
```

Using curly braces inside a lambda would return a lambda. It is should be updated as follows

```
this.bodyPublisher().map { p -> 
    val bs  = HttpResponse.BodySubscribers.ofString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    val fs = StringSubscriber(bs)
    p.subscribe(fs)
    bs.body.toCompletableFuture().join()
}
```